# Perl script in cgi-bin not executing shell script with arguments

Tags: linux, perl, shell, cgi

My perl script is present in cgi-bin/rel loaction. This snippet of the code is having issues:

```
system("./upd_test.sh $res_file $label >log/upload.log 2>&1 &"); ->does not work
system("./upd_test.sh"); ->works fine
```

i so not understand why this is happening. Apache server is used.

file permissions for the perl script are

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   apache 1935 Oct  8 12:37 upload_label.pl
```

file permissions for the shell script are

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root   apache  945 Oct  8 14:27 upd_test.sh
```

If i can call the shell script without arguments, why is the issue when i call it with arguments? The script does not get called at all. I have added a print in the shell script that writes into the `/tmp` location to verify if it gets executed.

I just found out if i remove the redirect it works fine, so system("./upd_test.sh $res_file $label") works fine, but i want to redirect the log as it is very important for my work.

Comment: Re "The script does not get called at all", How do you do know that? And if that's true, the shell will emit an error to STDERR. What error did you get?

Comment: You've updated the question, but you didn't answer the questions. What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

The current working directory isn't the directory where your CGI script is, so using ./ will not work.

Try using FindBin (https://metacpan.org/pod/FindBin) to get the directory or just hardcode the full path to the upd_test.sh script.

But... running the system() from CGI script (so, actually from the web page) is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

The error was with permissions and not with the re-direct. I had to do a chown to upd_test.sh, so that the owner was apache.
Although if i try to run ./upd_test.sh $res_file $label >log/upload.log 2>&1 & on shell it throws an error.
I figured the right way to call this on shell is ./upd_test.sh $res_file $label >& log/upload.log &.

P.S. i thought i had edited and posted the reply, but seems like that was not the case. Sorry for being so obscure.